# Simple Way to Scale Channels in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

It seems that given a multi-channel image `img` I cannot do this:

```
img *= cv::Scalar(1.5,0.5,2.1);
```

I'd like to scale each channel by a different *float* factor.
Is there a simple way to do this?

I *could* use `cv::transform()` but that seems like overkill (I also obviously don't want to *manually* and *explicitly* iterate on all the pixels).

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with iterating over all the pixels?

Comment: How do you envision scaling each channel without touching all the pixels? That's a bit of a contradiction, isn't it?

Comment: Of course all the pixels have to be accessed, but writing the loop manually is **verbose**, **bug-prone** and most likely **less efficient** than a dedicated function that can optimize (and maybe parallelize) access order as most OpenCV functions do.  
That's what operator overloading is for (though it's missing in this case).

Comment: split, multiply each channel by a scalar, merge?

Comment: @Miki: seriously? I'm trying to be efficient here and you're suggesting multiple memory allocations and copies?!

Comment: Yes. It's surprisingly fast, not verbose, not bug-prone, optimized...

Comment: No way. It's way slower than it should, *and* it's at least 3 lines of code.

Comment: I'd like to evaluate both the split/merge and the answer (and eventually see I'm wrong ;) ). No time for this, though. The answer however is probably what you're looking for

Comment: @Miki: fwiw my images are ~3Mpx, try it with such large images. Anyway, I accepted the answer below. It sucks that `cv::MatExpr`/`cv::Mat` does not overload operators with `cv::Scalar` types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `multiply`:

```
cv::Mat3b m = ... ;
cv::multiply(m, cv::Scalar(2, 3, 4), m);
```

or, as suggested by [@AdiShavit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591502/simple-way-to-scale-channels-in-opencv/45591916#comment78143817_45591916):

```
cv::Mat3b m = ... ;
m = m.mul(cv::Scalar(2, 3, 4));
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Just got this suggestion from @berak. Thanks. IIUC, it is essentially the same as using `cv::transform()`.

Comment: For completeness, this also works: `img = img.mul(Scalar(2,3,4));`